# Case When statement with dates

Tags: sql, oracle

My case when statement seems to be incorrect and I cant figure out what is wrong. It gives me the same dates for both create time and update time records.
here is how my data looks:

T1:

```
ID      create_time  
1      08/09/2016 07:30:20AM
```

T2:

```
ID   update_time  
1      
1   08/15/2016 09:41:46AM
```

I am expecting the following:

```
ID  TimeStamp  
1   08/09/2016 07:30:20AM  
1   08/15/2016 09:41:46AM
```

however my code returns values for create times for the 2 records. it looks like this:

```
ID  TimeStamp  
1   08/09/2016 07:30:20AM  
1   08/09/2016 07:30:20AM

select t1.id, t1.desc,
Case
WHEN t1.create_time IS NOT NULL
THEN t1.create_time
WHEN t2.update_time IS NOT NULL
THEN t2.update_time
END AS "TimeStamp"
from t1, t2
where t1.id=t2.id
AND ( t1.create_time BETWEEN TO_DATE ('01-AUG-2016 00:00:00',
                               'dd-mon-yyyy HH24:Mi:SS')
               AND TO_DATE ('31-AUG-2016 23:59:59',
                            'dd-mon-yyyy HH24:Mi:SS')
   OR (  t2.update_time
               BETWEEN TO_DATE ('01-AUG-2016 00:00:00',
                                'dd-mon-yyyy HH24:Mi:SS')
               AND TO_DATE ('31-AUG-2016 23:59:59',
                            'dd-mon-yyyy HH24:Mi:SS')
            )
        )
```

I also need to mark each record based on the create/update time as New/Update in a separate column. I was doing this using case when as below:

```
CASE 
WHEN (t1.create_time IS NOT NULL AND t2.update_time IS NULL)
THEN 'New'
WHEN t2.update_time IS NOT NULL
THEN 'Update'
END AS "Type"
```

but this seems to be bringing duplicates as follows:
ID  TimeStamp    Type
1   08/09/2016   New
1   08/09/2016   Update
1   08/15/2016   New
1   08/15/2016   Update

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
select t1.id, t1.desc,
       coalesce(t2.update_time, t1.create_time) as "TimeStamp"
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and
        t2.update_time >= date '2016-08-25' and 
        t2.update_time < date '2016-09-01'
where (t1.create_time >= date '2016-08-25' and
       t1.create_time < date '2016-09-01'
      ) or
      t2.update_time is not null;
```

EDIT:

You seem to want a list of update and create times for any record that has an update or create during the specified time period.  I think this looks like:

```
with ids as (
      select t1.id, t1.desc, t1.create_time
      from t1 join
           t2
           on t1.id = t2.id
      where (t1.create_time >= date '2016-08-25' and
             t1.create_time < date '2016-09-01'
            ) t or
            (t2.update_time >= date '2016-08-25' and 
             t2.update_time < date '2016-09-01'
            )
     )
select ids.*
from ids
union all
select ids.id, ids.desc, t2.update_time
from ids join
     t2
     on t2.id = ids.id
where t2.update_time is not null;  -- I'm not sure if the range should also be checked here.
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` with an `ON` clause.
- Just say no to archaic outer join syntax that even Oracle is deprecating.  Using explicit outer joins.
- Oracle supports the `date` keyword so you can input dates using ISO standard formats.

Comment: You know there are cases when old Oracle syntax for joins can't be avoided... for example a bug in the implementation of REFRESH FAST for materialized views prevents fast refreshing if the query to create the view contains ANSI joins. Since I learned this, I say "in most cases" rather than "always." :-)

Answer (score 0):

You do an outer join, so you will get two rows (all id's are 1). In the second one t2.update_time is NULL.

Your query, the way you wrote it, first tests for t1.create_time to be non-null. This is true for BOTH rows in the outer join. So only the FIRST "WHEN... THEN" is ever evaluated.

Please explain the logic of your desired output; just showing it, and showing a query that does NOT do what you want, does not constitute a "complete specification" of your requirement.

**EDIT**:  The OP in a Comment to this Answer stated what he needs to get is the create_time along with all the non-null update_time values.

This is easy and does not require a join, it requires a UNION (or UNION ALL). In the sample data all rows have the same ID; if in real life there are more ID's, one can be selected with the WHERE clause.

```
select id, create_time as timestamp from t1
union all
select id, update_time from t2 where update_time is not null;
```

(Possibly add  `ORDER BY id, timestamp`   -   if needed)

OP: If this is not the desired result, please explain how it is different from what you needed.

**EDIT NUMBER 2**: The OP added to the requirement - there needs to be a Type marker as well.

```
select id, create_time as timestamp , 'New' as type from t1
union all
select id, update_time, 'Update' from t2 where update_time is not null;
```

Comment: Hey - whoever downvotes answers, I don't care about ratings or reputation, but at least for the benefit of others, you could explain what's wrong with the answer. Otherwise we are all left guessing.

Comment: I wasn't downvote but I would suspect it is because your answer was a little cryptic in this case and you commented to the OP.  So perhaps someone mistook that as a comment not an answer?  Anyway, +1 for noticing and mentioning the main issue was that create_time is not null for both cases and is tested first which is why the OP is likely getting that result.  Gordon gave a good answer but missed specifically mentioning case order logic which your answer and OP specifically mention.  Normally I would expect that to be clearer in an answer from you though

Comment: @Matt - my first paragraph was meant to explain what is happening in the query at the highest level. There is a join (an outer join using Oracle deprecated syntax), but since the same ID exists in both tables, the join is in fact the same as an inner join. You get all two rows in the output. Then, in the second paragraph, I answered the OP's question, who wanted to know what was wrong. In the third, I said I don't know what he *meant* to do; if he wanted help with fixing the query, I needed to know what it was supposed to do in the first place. I hate guessing at requirements (as you may know)

Comment: I wasn't attacking trying to be helpful, your comment is more succinct than your answer and explains the id being duplicated more correctly.  As I said I think your answer is the most direct to what is wrong I just feel it was cryptic and not as clear as it could be.

Comment: @mathguy: I need to display the create time and update time for each record, that is the logic. After the create time is displayed, how do I display the update time for the 2nd row?

Comment: @mathguy: I just updated the query to remove the outerjoin, since it is not needed. I ran my query without the outerjoin and still get the same results of the duplicate create times.

Comment: @Skn - you have two "update times" in that table. Which one needs to be shown? The most recent? (Or is there always only one non-null time?) Can there be "funny stuff" in t1 as well?

Comment: No, t1 always has only 1 record for each Id with the create time. t2 can have multiple, which I want to display. the first update time is null, I do not need to display that; there will always be 1 null record for each Id indicating the create time in t2. I only want to display valid update times for each record along with the create time from t1. Also, I need to display these times in the same column.

Comment: See the EDIT in the answer (in a minute).

Comment: @mathguy: Ok this seems to have worked but I have a new issue now. I will add my issue to my original post.